# How to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[n,n+1)} f(x) dx$ if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. I need to calculate the following integral: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[n,n+1)} f(x) dx$$ but I don't really how to begin with...

I would be really thankful if someone could give me a hint.

I think that  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[n,n+1)} f(x) dx$$ should be equal to  $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx$$ but I don't get to a solution... I know it's value is finite because $f$ is an integrable function. Is it possible to say anything else about this integral?

Comment: HINT: Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: But this teorem only affects what's inside the integral, doesn't it? How could I change the limits of the integral?

Comment: Consider rewriting any integral over a set $A$ as $\int_A f = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f\chi_{A}$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an alternative answer not using dominated convergence. Recall that $S \mapsto \int_S |f|$ is a measure so by disjoint additivity, $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_{[n, n + 1)} |f(x)| = \int_{[1, \infty)} |f(x)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R} } |f(x)| < \infty $$ which implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[n, n +1)} |f(x)| = 0$ since otherwise, the sum would diverge.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, the series equals $\int_{[1,+\infty)}|f|\le\int_{\Bbb R}|f|<\infty$. A very good answer.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Right, I totally missed that. I'll edit that into the answer. Thanks!